# How can I check in javascript inputbox for empty space using "enter"

Tags: javascript

How can I check my input for a bunch of new lines, I know it's not majorly practical, but I wan't to be 100% my inputs are not breakable.

Hence how can I check if an input box in javascript is just a bunch of spaces, at the moment mine just checks for whitespace.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex:

```
if (str.replace(/[\s\n\r]+/g, "") != "")
{
    // if you remove spaces and line breaks, it doesn't equal nothing
}
```

**EDIT** - it should be faster

```
if (/\S/.test(str))
{
    // found something other than spaces or line breaks

    // "\S" should match any character that is not a space or line break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use trim and check the length.

```
// it is a bunch of spaces
if(inputValue.trim().length == 0){ /* ... */}
```

Answer (score 0):

A space is just a bunch of whitespaces. So you can check with the following method:

```
if(s.indexOf(' ') >= 0) return true;
```

You might also want to trim your input instead of checking for the potential presence of whitespaces:

```
 s.trim();
```