# Google Script: Check if Browser.inputBox is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to end the script from running if Browser.inputBox pop-up window has no value. Below is part of the code (Line: 07) where this should go in. I tried using  **== "blank"** but does not work.
I'm novice in coding.

Google Spreadsheet

Thanks in Advance!

```
    // Below is to check Project Name.
  if (ss.getSheetByName('Feedback').getRange('I1').isBlank()){
    var prjName = Browser.inputBox ('ERROR!','Project Name is missing\\n\\nPlease Enter it below',Browser.Buttons.OK);
  if (prjName == "cancel"){
     Browser.msgBox('CANCELLED!', 'The feedback details have NOT been saved', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      return;}
  else if (prjName == "blank"){
      Browser.msgBox('CANCELLED!', 'The feedback details have NOT been saved', Browser.Buttons.OK);
      return;}   
    else              
      s1.getRange('I1').setValue(prjName);
  }
```

Comment: `"blank"` means a string with the value `blank`, so of course it cannot reflect when something is empty or holds a nullstring `""`. Consider reviewing the Apps Script documentation on the `Browser` class, and also the `Ui` class. You may find their enumerations helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I went through the Apps Script Documentation related to my requirement. Maybe I'm not qualified enough to figure out the solution from the documentation or maybe there is no direct answer to what I am looking for. I'll keep looking around anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to make sure it is not just spaces or a blank response. You can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470431/how-can-i-check-in-javascript-inputbox-for-empty-space-using-enter). For future reference, check javascript solution also when trying to find a solution for Google App Script. Google app script is based on javascript, so most javascript solution work for App Script. Again, most not all!

Comment: Perfect Thanks for the suggestion. `else if (prjName == 0)` worked for me.
Have a good day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check in javascript inputbox for empty space using "enter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470431/how-can-i-check-in-javascript-inputbox-for-empty-space-using-enter)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
 if (prjName == "" || prjName == "cancel"){
 Browser.msgBox('CANCELLED!', 'The feedback details have NOT been saved', 
 Browser.Buttons.OK);
 return;
```

}