# If var is empty, replace text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am sending an email when the user submits the form. This is working perfectly but I now want to check if the variable is empty (user has not populated that form answer) and do something with it depending on the result.

**EXAMPLE**

A populated `otherPics` variable looks like this:

`http://google-drive-link-1`

or

`http://google-drive-link-1, http://google-drive-link-2, ...`

I want to check if the variable `otherPics` is empty. If it is, I want to replace it with the string `"n/a"`, if it is not empty, I want to replace `,` with `<br>`

**CODE**

```
function sendEmailNoti(e) {
   var timeStamp = e.namedValues["Timestamp"];
   var qType = e.namedValues["Query Type"];
   var engEmail = e.namedValues["Email address"];
   var jID = e.namedValues["ID"];
   var DataPic = e.namedValues["Data Image"];
   var otherPics = e.namedValues["Other Images"];
   var QueryDesc = e.namedValues["Query"];


if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(otherPics).length === 0) {
 otherPics = "n/a";  //var is empty
}
else {
 otherPics.replaceText(", ","<br>"); //var is not empty
}

   var subject =  jID + " - " + qType;
   var email = "email@example.com";
   var message = 
    "<strong>" + "EngEmail: " + "</strong><br>" + engEmail + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "Timestamp" + "</strong><br>" + timeStamp + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "Query Type" + "</strong><br>" + qType + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "ID" + "</strong><br>" + jID + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "Data Image" + "</strong><br>" + DataPic + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "Additional Images" + "</strong><br>" + otherPics + "<br><br>" + 
    "<strong>" + "Query" + "</strong><br>" + QueryDesc + "<br><br>" +
    "<br><br><i>foo bar</i>";

    MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: email,
     replyTo: engEmail,
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message
   });
}
```

Comment: I swear there was a question that was just about this, but was for response to `Browser.msgBox`. Anyway, it linked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588229/how-to-check-if-form-input-has-value/2588313#2588313 which has methods you can use for this exact purpose.

Comment: The comments in this question may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391788/google-script-check-if-browser-inputbox-is-not-blank#comment85785295_49391788 For string replacement, use this method: [`string.replace(regex, newStr)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), i.e. `"my old, old string".replace(/old/, "new")` yields `"my new, new string"` while `"my old, old string".replace("old", "new")` yields `"my new, old string"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Conditional (Ternary) Operator, like so:

variablename = (condition) ? value1:value2

var otherPics =  (e.namedValues["Other Images"]) ? e.namedValues["Other Images"]:"n/a"